# Same API works on Nougat (7.0), but does not work on Marshmallow OS (6.0 and below)

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am calling SAP API's with SSL configuration in my app I got response code 200 when app runs on Nougat it works fine.

But on Marshmallow OS 6.0 and below, it gives

> 400 (Bad request)

I'm unable to find the route cause. Please assist.

Gradle piece of code as per below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Target SDK version to 23, hope your problem will be solved